# MySQL Connection Refused on MAMP Pro

Tags: mysql, sockets, osx-mavericks, mamp-pro

I apologize if this is a duplicate, but so far I have not found any answers to this question. I recently installed MAMP Pro, and have been having some issues with MySQL. The display seems to indicate that the MySQL has started, but the port does not seem to be open.
Here is some info about my laptop: http://puu.sh/5lxJU.png
Here is the display: http://puu.sh/5lxku.png

I ran a port scan on my computer and these are the results:

```
$ nmap 127.0.0.1

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-11-17 18:06 EST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.0028s latency).
Not shown: 498 closed ports, 498 filtered ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
631/tcp  open  ipp
8021/tcp open  ftp-proxy

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.61 seconds
```

It does not appear that MySQL is running. I have the port set to 3306. It does not look like there are any errors but here is the bottom of my error log anyway:

```
131117 18:05:54 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
131117 18:05:54 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
131117 18:05:54 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
131117 18:05:54 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
131117 18:05:54 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
131117 18:05:55  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
131117 18:05:56 InnoDB: 5.5.33 started; log sequence number 1595675
131117 18:05:56 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
131117 18:05:56 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.33'  socket: '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 0  Source distribution
```

I have already tried restarting my computer, is there anything else short of deleting everything and reinstalling MAMP Pro I can do?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem was that it was only letting me directly access the socket. Solution:

Go to the Server > MySQL tab and make sure that "Allow local access only" is **not** checked
Click the apply button and everything works fine

Comment: yes, only allowing access on the socket is what "skip-networking" does.

Comment: @mezod no it doesn't. are you sure you are trying to connect to the right port? look at preferences->ports mamp has weird defaults.

Comment: yup thanks, that was the issue, I was using 8889 instead of 3306

Answer (score 11):

I never used the MAMP distribution, but it sounds to me like your `my.cnf` have the `skip-networking` parameter set.

**EDIT**: 
A bit of googling showed that MAMP does in-fact set the skip-networking parameter as default. Simply comment out `skip-networking` in your configuration file and you should be fine :)

Comment: Thank you, I think that may be the problem but every time I change the config file it changes it back when I start the server. How do I prevent it from being reverted every time MAMP starts?

Comment: http://www.drupalcoder.com/blog/a-better-way-to-create-mysql-configuration-file-mycnf-on-mamp.html :)

Comment: After unchecking the local access only button, this line changed automatically

Comment: Brilliant!  After hours of searching for this solution, commenting skip-networking was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the setting to fix this is still in the MySQL tab, but the checkbox is now called "Allow network access to MySQL".